# Determine the sinusoidal function that will fall entirely within the exponential envelope.

Tags: functions, exponential-function, graphing-functions, control-theory, math-software

How do I determine the sinusoidal function that will lie perfectly between the two exponential functions (envelope): $1+e^{\left(-2t\right)}$ and $1-e^{\left(-2t\right)}$?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What have you tried to do? In those situations, just plot the different curves on a graph and see how you find the solution.

Comment: As @KBS has said, use for example Geogebra for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want a damped sinusoidal, of the form $$A=f(t)\sin(\omega t)+b$$
Then take $b$ to be the average of your envelope functions. In this case $b=1$. Choose $f(t)$ to be half the difference between the envelope functions, $$f(t)=e^{-2t}$$
So $$A(t)=e^{-2t}\sin(\omega t)+1$$
Notice that since $\sin(\omega t)$ is between $-1$ and $1$, $$1-e^{-2t}\le A(t)\le 1+e^{-2t}$$